# Is there any simple way to append the dataTables data using Ajax json response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, datatable

My json response are in the following format.

```
[{
  "directory": "random_code",
  "name": "random_code1",
  "mailing_name": "random_code",
  "address": "random_code",
  "statutory": "random_code",
  "state": "random_code",
  "pincode": "random_code",
  "telephone_num": "random_code",
  "email": "random_code",
  "currency_symbol": "h",
  "maintain": "random_code",
  "financial_year": "random_code1",
  "books_beginning": "random_code1",
  "educational_mode": "hj",
  "vault_password": "hj",
  "security_control": "h",
  "curreny_formal_name": "jh",
  "num_decimal_places": "jh",
  "symbol_suffixed": "j",
  "currency_symbol_decimal": "h",
  "amount_in_millions": "jhj",
  "space_between_symbol_amount": "h",
  "decimal_places_for_printing_amount_in_words": "jhj"
}, {
  "directory": "random_code",
  "name": "random_code2",
  "mailing_name": "random_code",
  "address": "jh",
  "statutory": "jh",
  "state": "jhjhjh",
  "pincode": "jh",
  "telephone_num": "jh",
  "email": "jhj",
  "currency_symbol": "hj",
  "maintain": "hj",
  "financial_year": "random_code2",
  "books_beginning": "random_code2",
  "educational_mode": "h",
  "vault_password": "hj",
  "security_control": "hj",
  "curreny_formal_name": "jh",
  "num_decimal_places": "jhj",
  "symbol_suffixed": "hjh",
  "currency_symbol_decimal": "jh",
  "amount_in_millions": "jh",
  "space_between_symbol_amount": "jh",
  "decimal_places_for_printing_amount_in_words": "jhh"
}]
```

My code in the script tag is the following, id name is datatable2 and wants tp dsplay all the data that is getting in response from ajax to Datatable. Using the following code, I can able to see the values in a table but it's not in DataTables.

```
<table id="datatable2" class="table order-column hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Financial Year</th>
            <th>Book Beginning from</th>
            <th width="150px">Actions</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>

    $(function() {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/company/",
          dataType: "json",
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(data) {
            var trHTML = '';
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
              trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>' + item.financial_year + '</td><td>' + item.books_beginning + '</td><td><a href="/company_app/edit/1/" class="btn ink-reaction btn-floating-action btn-warning"><i class="md md-edit"></i> </a><a href="/order/delete/1/" class="btn ink-reaction btn-floating-action btn-danger" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this?\')"><i class="md md-delete"></i> </a><a href="/order/1/" class="btn ink-reaction btn-floating-action btn-primary"><i class="md md-print"></i> </a></td></tr>';
            });
            $('#datatable2').append(trHTML);
          }
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

But it's not adding in dataTable. Can anyone help me to append the same inside of datatable? I'm noob in datatables.

HTML edited.

Comment: Why not keep it simple and use the built-in AJAX features of Datatables? https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html

Comment: are you sure is HTML Table Name  datatable2  ?  Run Your Project on Chrome. Right Click on your datatable. Choose Inspect element on popup menu. What is  HTML Table id  ? Use this id as a selector.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you please elaborate how can I use this ? I just just want to show the 4 fields i.e., name, financial_year, books_beginning and action field. How can I do that using ajax attribute in DataTables() ?

Comment: @CAGDASAYDIN Yes I am sure. I have updated my code. Kindly Check it and lemme know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your ajax call inside the built-in ajax parameter when initializing a datatable, and send the data to datatable's callback method:

```
$('#datatable2').dataTable({
  "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
            $.ajax({
               url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/company/",
               dataType: "json",
               type: 'GET',
               success: function(data) {
                  callback(data);
               }
            });
  },
  "columns": columns
});
```

Also, if you want to customize your rows, this should also be done in the "columns" parameter, for example:

```
columns = [
   { "data": "item" },
   { "data": "financial_year" },
   { "data": "books_beginning" },
   { "data": null,
     "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
         // you can even get the data from other columns here
         // and render whatever you want on these cells
         return '</td><td><a href="/company_app/edit/1/" class=...'
     }
   }
]
```

there are plenty of examples in the datatables documentation, with different levels of customization:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: Thank you for your Answer but when I add columns, the datatable hangs on loading.. why so ?

Comment: There could be many reasons. 
Is the information coming correctly from the server?
Did you call the callback method on success?
Does the console show any errors when loading the table? That's usually the case.

Comment: When I write console.log(data) above the callback(data); on success, it's showing me the data properly but when I write console.log(data) below the callaback(data); on success, it displays nothing in console. I guess the callback method id not properly called. I directly copied your code of ajax by the way.

Comment: have you correctly installed the datatables CDN? or added it locally?
try create any basic datatable like `$('#datatable2').DataTable();` and see if it loads correctly. Usually when it does, and the data doesn't show, it should tell u what the error is on the console.
Try doing this: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html, with the js and HTML and see if it loads like it shows there.

Comment: I have added it locally and yeah its working when I remove the ajax and column parameter, data can be stored to datatable properly using DTL but when I get the  json value from ajax, I can't load it in datatables. Please guide me.

Comment: are you using the default format that datatables uses when calling callback?
`{ "data": (your list) }`

Comment: Inside the ajax attribute in datatables, my success method looks like .....  success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                  callback(data);
               }

Comment: yeah but how does your data object look like? is it a dict with a "data" key?
`{ "data": [ {"directory": ..., "}, {"directory": ..., "} ] }`

Comment: 0: Object { directory: "jhjh", name: "jh", mailing_name: "dfd", … }
​
1: Object { directory: "jhj", name: "hjh", mailing_name: "jh", … }
​
length: 2 

This is how I can see my data object. I don't have "data" key,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220039/discussion-between-camieq-and-sodmzs).